# CSS: Align even elements

Tags: css

[Here is my layout](http://jsfiddle.net/JLkMa/). I have a container 508px wide with divs inside. I want to align left column (odd divs) to the left, and right column to the right. I tried `nth-child(even)` - but it doesn't adjust the right margin. One- Why doesn't it work? Two - is there a more elegant solution to this?

**CSS**

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: "\0020"; display: block; height: 0; overflow: hidden; }  
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }  
.clearfix { zoom: 1; } 


#products {width:508px;background-color:#FFC;}
#products > div {
    float:left;
    margin: 0 30px 30px 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#products > div:nth-child(even) {margin: 0 0 30px 0;background-color:#CCC;}
#products a {font-weight:normal;}
#products img {
    width:224px;
    height:120px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="products" class="clearfix">
        <div>
            <div><a href=""><img src="" alt=""></a></div>
            <div><a href="">Product 1</a></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div><a href=""><img src="" alt=""></a></div>
            <div><a href="">Product 2</a></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div><a href=""><img src="" alt=""></a></div>
            <div><a href="">Product 3</a></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div><a href=""><img src="" alt=""></a></div>
            <div><a href="">Product 4</a></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div><a href=""><img src="" alt=""></a></div>
            <div><a href="">Product 5</a></div>
        </div>                    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried making the even divs float right?

Like this:

```
#products > div:nth-child(even) {margin: 0 0 30px 0;background-color:#CCC; float: right;}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JLkMa/1/)

Comment: That works! Any idea why it's ignoring my new 0 right margin?

Comment: It's not ignoring it, but the even divs simply aren't flushed to the right by default, since in HTML/CSS things go from left to right.

Comment: Correction: In your case, _all_ divs were floated to the left, so they were sticking as far to the left as margin would let them.